# In AngularJs, if record consist of more than 3 rows then HTTP request fails to send data to the server

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-directive

In AngularJs, when I send three rows of data to the server, it sends successfully, but if more than three then it throws an error in console. error image is attached.

```
$http({
                    url: '/scrap/CSVCreator',
                    method: "GET",
                    params: { CSVdata: $scope.CSVfileData }
                }).then(
                    function successCallback(response) {
                        var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
                        hiddenElement.href = "/scrap/GetCSV";
                        hiddenElement.click();

                        $scope.loading = false;
                    },
                    function errorCallback(response) {
                        $scope.loading = false;
                        $scope.validationmessage(response.data);
                        return;
                    });
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should use POST to send large data as GET request has limited URL length.

Comment: [URL length has limits.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) Can you say what is the length of the URL in your case, when more than 3 rows are selected?

Comment: Seconding @SushantYadav here. You are generating a resource from a large set of data, which is more fitting for a POST request.

Comment: I have tried post also. same problem. the length of the row is in hundreds or can be more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<system.web>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxQueryStringLength = "1200000" maxUrlLength="1200000" />
</system.web>
```

And also add

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxQueryString="1200000"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: you answered your own question and accepted it . nice